# Serializing <input> based on class

Tags: jquery

Hello I am trying to serialize a form and submit it into my php. I have found that using the normal .serialize command turns spaces into '+' so I am trying my luck at passing a JSON.

I was wondering how you could select only the input values with a class = pass?

```
<input class="pass">
```

I am using the bottom code to turn stuff into JSON, however I am stuck on how I can select by classes?

http://jsfiddle.net/r3S5U/10/

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
```

Just change the form selector to .pass:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($('.pass').serializeObject()));
```

Only DOM elements with the 'pass' class will be serialized now.

Comment: Tried `serializeObject` and did not work. But works `serialize`. Tried with jquery-1.10.2.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$('.pass').serializeObject();
```

So, you will select only the input with class = pass.

Regards